# Getting invalid user ID error when creating a new user with wp_insert_user

Tags: php, users, mysql, errors, import

I'm trying to insert users into wordpress from a foreign database and I've prepared my `$userdata` as

```
foreach ($users_out as $key_u => $value_u) {
    $user_id = $value_u['writer_id'];
    $user_login = $value_u['username'];
    $user_nicename = $value_u['username'];
    $user_email = $value_u['email'];
    $user_display_name = $value_u['username'];
    $user_nickname = $value_u['username'];
    $user_first_name = $value_u['fname'];
    $user_last_name = $value_u['sname'];
    $user_description = $value_u['forum_sig'];
    $user_user_registered = $value_u['created'];
    $user_role = $value_u['title'];

    if ($value_u['fname'] != '') {
        $userdata = array(
            'ID' => $user_id,
            'user_pass' => '',
            'user_login' => $user_login,
            'user_nicename' => $user_nicename,
            'user_email' => $user_email,
            'display_name' => $user_display_name,
            'nickname' => $user_nickname,
            'first_name' => $user_first_name,
            'last_name' => $user_last_name,
            'description' => $user_description,
            'user_registered' => $user_user_registered,
            'role' => $user_role,
        );
    }

    $user_one =wp_insert_user( $userdata );
}
```

Where I have array of users. My `$userdata` looks like:

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 79
    [user_pass] => 
    [user_login] => John Doe
    [user_nicename] => John Doe
    [user_email] => john.doe@mail.com
    [display_name] => John Doe
    [nickname] => John Doe
    [first_name] => John
    [last_name] => Doe
    [description] => This is a user description
    [user_registered] => 2010-05-16 15:33:33
    [role] => Skribent
)
```

Now I don't know if it's because the role is in the Swedish or what, but I get `invalid user ID` error thrown and no user is inserted.

What could be the issue? I've searched if the user with that ID already exists, and nothing. Only registered is admin (I'm doing this locally).

Comment: What's the outpuf from `var_dump(  $user_one );` ?

Comment: `print_r` gives: `WP_Error Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [invalid_user_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Invalid user ID.
                )

        )

    [error_data] => Array
        (
        )

)`

Comment: This means you're trying to update a user with user id 79 and that user doesn't exist?

Comment: You're also defining `$user_data` inside the `if`, but *always* executing `wp_insert_user` - this should also be inside the `if`

Comment: I figured out the issue. I've tried to insert the ID and I had to leave that empty, and I'll probably need to assign that via `wp_update_user()`.